# How does fuel stabilizer work chemically?

Tags: gasoline, long-term-storage, fuel-stabilizer

I frequently use fuel stabilizer in my lawn tractors when storing them over winter, and have found it actually fairly effective.  I have also remarked that I am able to store gas much longer and have it usable in string trimmers, lawn mowers, etc. if I have stored it with a fuel stabilizer in it.

However, I fail to see how fuel stabilizer actually works.  I understand that it prevents moisture content increases, and prevents the evaporation of the volatile components of gas?  Is this the case, and if so, how does that actually work?

Comment: Im sure those are trade secrets covered by patents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fuel stabilizer actually separates from the gasoline after you let it sit for a while and forms a film on top separating the air from the gas, preventing the gas from oxidizing and picking up moisture from the air.

Comment: Huh, fascinating, and welcome to mechanics.stackexchange.com!  Do you have any references you could link to?

Comment: https://www.toro.com/fuelfacts/